# OpenLayers 3 Convert Pixel Coordinates to Lat Long

Tags: openlayers-3

I am new to OpenLayers and would appreciate any help I can get. How do you convert from pixel-based-coordinates to lat/lon? I'm using OL3 to view and draw features on a static image (6494 x 7687 jpg) using projection:

```
  var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'xkcd-image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: [0, 0, 6494, 7687]
  });
```

At the end of a polygan draw I have this, which works fine:

```
draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
  var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  console.log("YOU DREW A Polygon with coord="+coord);
});
```

Is there an easy way to convert the above pixel-based coordinates of the polygon to Lat/Lon coordinates?  I do have the lat/lons of the four corners of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying a custom pixel projection, configure your static image source with the `imageExtent` set to your corner coordinates, and set its projection to `'EPSG:4326'`:

```
new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  // ...
  imageExtent: [minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat],
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
})
```

If you want to show your image without being distorted, you have to configure your view with `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` as well. You'll then be working with geographic coordinates throughout.

Something similar is also shown in one of the official examples: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html. The difference is that raster reprojection is used there, because image and view are in different projection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That makes a lot of sense.  I need to store both lat/lon coordinates and pixel coordinates.  How difficult would be to now convert lat/lon coordinates to pixel coordinates?  Thanks again.